# ajax RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, servlets

my jsp

```
for (int i =0;i<bookings.size();i++){
    %>  
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" id="name" ><%=bookings.get(i).getname()%></td>
    <td id="type"><%=bookings.get(i).gettype()%></td>
    <td rowspan="3"><button type="button" onclick="cancelPost(this)">Cancel</button>
            <p style="color:red;">confirm</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <span id="from"><%=bookings.get(i).from()%></span>    
     <span id="to"><%=bookings.get(i).to()%></span>
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SSN: <span id="Ssn"><%=bookings.get(i).getssn()%></span></td>
  </tr>
```

my js

```
function cancelPost(x){
var rowIndex = $(x).closest('table').index(); 
var type = $(x).closest('table').find("#type").text();
type = type.replace(/\s/g, '');
var from = $(x).closest('table').find("#from").text();
var to = $(x).closest('table').find("#to").text();
var Ssn = $(x).closest('table').find("#Ssn").text();
var name = $(x).closest('table').find("#name").text();
name = name.replace(/\s/g, '');
alert(rowIndex+";"+type+";"+from+";"+to+";"+Ssn+";"+name);
$.ajax({
    url:"/deleteBookingServlet",
    type:"post",
    data:{
        name:name,
        Ssn: Ssn,
        from: from,
        to: to,
        type:type
    },
    success:function(result,testStatus){
        if(result=="true"){
            alert("success");
        }else{
            alert("fail");
        }
    },
error:function(xhr,errorMessage,e){
    alert(xhr.status);
}
});
}
```

The alert window shows all correct information, which means these variables are actually not undefined. Then it got stuck after I closed the alert window. Similar ajax code in my other jsp files works well, but except this one. I really don't know why. Could someone help me please.

Comment: The error indicates an infinite loop somewhere!

Comment: @MICKY, if the same code is working in other jsps then the issue might be in servlet code. add your `/deleteBookingServlet` servlet code to question.

Comment: one suggestion for your js code, instead calling `$(x).closest('table')` multiple times assign it a variable and use the variable to fetch element values. it will help you to reduce the number iterations lookup for the respective table object.
Ex: `var tbl = $(x).closest('table'); 
var from = tbl.find("#from").text();
....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong in the servlet, the ajax code that I posted here was correct.